# sendrawtransaction RPC format across core versions

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-core-development

Has there been any changes across core versions for the sendrawtransaction interface. I am trying to understand if upgrading the core version from say 12 to 15 needs a change in serialization. I'd also like to know if there are any versions across which such upgrade would fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sendrawtransaction` takes transactions in the network serialization format. There is a new network serialization format for segwit transactions, so such transactions would be broadcast in one format for 0.12 and a different one in 0.15. If you are not making segwit transactions, then `sendrawtransaction` has not changed and you can use it in 0.15 as you did with 0.12.

Comment: @achow101 :  Is it possible to know across which versions was the serialization changed in the past as well ?  I assume this applies to all clients across the board ( Unlimtied , ABC etc). Thanks!

Comment: You can read the release notes of each release. The serialization format will only change when a fork happens (both hard or soft), but not every time there is a fork. The only time the serialization format has changed is between 0.12 and 0.13 with the introduction of Segwit. The format has only changed to allow a new format; the original format is still supported by all versions.